# filter(drop-shadow) dissappear for some menu elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have a little triangle under my menu that points to the current active menu item, using the activeClassName of Gatsbys Link component. It blends together nicely with my content container, or it should.

Problem is that the boundary links loose the filter(drop-shadow) effect. When inspecting the computed elements the css is exactly the same between the middle and the boundary Link components, even though the drop-shadow is obviously missing. I'm very new to css design so I don't have the knowledge to pinpoint exactly why this is happening, incompatible rules..etc.

[image: menu bar]

Here is my code

**Navbar.js**

```js
const NavBar = () => {
  const {
    siteMetadata: { menuLinks },
  } = useSiteMetadata()
  console.log(navMain)
  return (
    <nav className={navMain}>
      <ul className={navList}>
        {menuLinks.map(link => (
          <li key={link.name}>
            <Link
              to={link.link}
              className={navItem}
              activeClassName={activeNavItem}
            >
              {link.name}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

**Navbar.module.scss**

```
.nav-item {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.active-nav-item {
  position: relative;
  color: #663f18 !important;
  &::after {
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 40px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 4px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your failing items get the `.active-nav-item` class? Is it possible that it's because the route aren't fully matching?

Comment: ```.navbar-module--active-nav-item--xcLrC``` is set on the element when inspecting in chrome. The triangle is placed correctly so that part is working,